# How to put an x-coordinates of a points as extra x ticks?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

I need to put x-coordinates of a points as extra x ticks, but common way is irrational, because there can be many points and duplicate them in `extra x ticks` is poor.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}

    %---------------------------------------------------------

            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                ]
                \begin{axis}[
                    width=\linewidth, axis lines = middle,
                    extra x ticks = {1.1, 2.2,3.3}, % irrational decision, because there can be many points
                    xtick=data,
                ]
                \addplot[] {x};
                \addplot[color=red,mark=*, only marks] coordinates {
                        (1.1,1)
                        (2.2,2)
                        (3.3,3)
                    };
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

    %---------------------------------------------------------
    \end{document}
```

Comment: *All* the points? `xtick=data` does that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, all the points, but from only one `\addplot coordinates` plot!

Comment: Or, I think, may be is it possible to show x coordinates near  points via `nodes near coords`?

Comment: Well, `xtick=data` only uses the coordinates from the *first* `\addplot`, so that doesn't have to be a problem. And yes, you can show x-coordinates via `nodews near coords`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
xtick=data, % data points from first \addplot
extra x ticks={-4,...,4} % regularly spaced ticks
```

you'll get ticks for each point in the first `\addplot`, and regularly spaced ticks in addition. It can get a bit messy though. One way of separating them would be to shift the coordinate ticks down, i.e.

```
xticklabel style={yshift=-15pt},
extra x tick style={tick label style={yshift=15pt}}
```

The second line is needed because the first one also affects the extra ticklabels.

For `nodes near coords`, adding `point meta=x,nodes near coords` in the options of an `\addplot` will add the x-values next to the points in that plot. The code below demonstrates both of these.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}

    %---------------------------------------------------------

            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                ]
                \begin{axis}[
                    width=\linewidth, 
                    axis lines = middle,
                    xtick=data, % data points from first \addplot
                    extra x ticks={-4,...,4}, % regularly spaced ticks
                    xticklabel style={yshift=-15pt},
                    extra x tick style={tick label style={yshift=15pt}}
                ]
                \addplot[color=red,mark=*,
                         only marks,
                         point meta=x, % use x-value for nodes near coords
                         nodes near coords
                        ] coordinates {
                        (1.1,1)
                        (2.2,2)
                        (3.3,3)
                    };
                \addplot[] {x};

                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

    %---------------------------------------------------------
    \end{document}
```